# Library MPDF (PHP): Sometimes gives Internal Server Error (500) inserver not lcal

Tags: php, jquery, mpdf, internal-server-error

I have implemented the generation of a report with php (Mpdf library) and jquery. It works correctly both locally and in the final server, but in some cases in the productive server it gives error 500. The same does not happen locally, with the same case.

Both servers have php version 5.5.38. The application log shows no errors with error_reporting (E_ALL).
What can I compare from both phpinfo? What could be the problem?
I appreciate any help to solve it.

Comment: Can you explaine which is the exactly case that error appear? Value is from db?

Comment: What does the server log show when you get the 500 error? That is an error at the server level not PHP.

Comment: @SimoneRossaini from console show only "500 (Internal Server Error)" in jquery code, but this code dosent have any error. The same case works locally, and another report works on the server too.

Comment: @Dave I requesting records from the provider, I don't see them in the panel. Any idea where I could find them?

Comment: The server error log is usually available in cPanel someplace. It might be labeled Apache error log or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

The server error log show: " Allowed memory size".

I solved it using:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');
```

Thanks